# How to override module & component template outside the template folder in Joomla 3.x

Tags: templates, plugins, joomla, overriding

I know, I can override templates with this `/templates/mytemplate/html/...`

I need to know if it's possible to change the `JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath` for example with a plugin to add another folder with custom templates.

I'm developping a template to re-use for all my clients but sometimes, I need to override my own overrided template. I make update of my template each times for all my clients, if I need to change the default.php `mod_menu`. I can change it but if 1 week later I update the template on this website, my own original template override the custom template espacially for this website.

I want (if it's possible) to create a plugin/extension and inside this plugin, add all my `default` template with the same system.

The overriding order will be :

1. HTML Template standard overriding
2. My `plugin/extension` html folder
3. Standard `tmpl` from module or component

I don't know if it's clear...

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand: You want to push general updates to your template, but keep any changes you made to this specific website?